# Loading multiple packages in a single kie session?

Tags: session, package, drools, rules, kie

I have two packages a and b having different rule files. Right now I am using two sessions to load the rules. Is there a way I can load rules from both the packages in a single session?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules_a" packages="rules_a">
        <ksession name="ksession1"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="rules_b" packages="rules_b">
        <ksession name="ksession2"/>
 </kmodule>
```

Can I pass something like:  packages = {"rules_a", "rules_b"} ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a packages attribute of kiebase, below is an example of how to include the packages rules1, rules2 in kiebase.

```
<kbase name="rules_12" packages="rules1,rules2">
```

From drools [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.9.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_kieoverviewsection):
[image: drools description]

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this section of the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_creatingandbuildingakieproject), you can pass a comma separated list of packages when building a KieBase.

Another possibility is to create a KieBase that includes others. That same section of the documentation shows how to do it.

Hope it helps,

Comment: is It possible to create two sessions in <kmodule>?